# Enviando variables por ajax recibo un objeto vacio

Tags: php, jquery, symfony3

estoy intentando enviar una variable que obtengo de un input hacia mi controlador de la siguiente manera

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".autocomplete").on('blur',function(){
        var occ = $("#oculto_id").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('reg_validacion') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: occ,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                //si hago un alert(occ); me imprime la variable,lo que significa que el input no esta en null
            }
        });
    });
});
```

pero el **alert(data)** me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el controlador no estoy recibiendo nada.

```
public function validatection(Request $request)
{
    $varpost=$request->query->get("occ");

    dump($varpost);
    die();
    return $varpost;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna sugerencia de como puedo obtener el valor occ del input en el controlador?

Comment: a ver intenta enviar con `data:{occ:occ}`  o  `data:{occ}`

Comment: Si, eso también lo había intentado pero nada. igual hay un post con el mismo problema pero en laravel.  https://laraveles.com/foro/viewtopic.php?id=3631

Comment: ya verificaste que este bien la url? y sea accedida desde fuera? has pruebas con un ejemplo sencillo sin usar ajax

Comment: si, la url esta bien, ya lo verifique también!

Comment: Te retorna algo cuando envias 'occ' manualmente? sin usar ajax

Comment: Intenta con `data:{occ:occ}` y en php `$varpost=$request->request->get('occ');`

Comment: Ya, tu problema es que usas `query`(cuando es GET) en vez de `request`(cuando es por POST),

Comment: entiendo, pero igual con $varpost=$request->request->get('occ'); en el controlador recibo null

Comment: Has lo que te comenta @DarckBlezzer pon solo $request->get('occ')

Comment: Todo igual amigos, NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema, no se esta mandando correctamente el valor OCC,

**En ajax seria**

```
data: {occ:occ}
// o de esta maneta
data: {occ}
// o de esta maneta
data: {"occ":occ}
```

Recuerda que estas mandando por `POST` y en symfony se obtiene la variable de esta manera

```
// parametros por $_GET
$request->query->get('occ');

// parametros por $_POST
$request->request->get('occ');
```

Si no puedes con estas, intenta con alguna de estas:

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
$this->get('request');
$request->query->get('keyWord');
$request->request->get('keyWord');
$request->get('keyWord');
$request->request->getInt('keyWord');
$request->query->all();
```

Comment: todas me devuelven [] o null o varpost=$request->request->getInt('occ'); me devuelve 0

Comment: Tenias razón, tenia que reemplazar query - request. pero también quitar el __dump__ por que cortaba la secuencia antes de el return, por eso devolvía el objeto vacío, por ultimo regresarlo a la vista como json $response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData($varpost); GRACIAS POR TU AYUDA.

Comment: otra cosa que seria muy bueno es: que actualices tu post con Respuesta: o Solución: y el código solucionado, para que posibles personas puedan ver que era el error.

Answer (score 1):

El problema se encuentra en el controlador, cuando envías los datos por metodo GET lo recibes de esta manera:

```
$varpost=$request->query->get("occ");
```

Y cuando envias los datos por POST lo debes recibir de esta manera.

```
$varpost=$request->request->get("occ");
```

También puedes enviarla directamente por la URL (GET), ajustando tu url en el metodo ajax de esta forma:

```
url =  "{{ path('ruta_del_controlador', {'datos_envio':'x1'}) }}";
url = url.replace('x1', variable);
```

Comment: entiendo. pero con $varpost=$request->request->get("occ"); sigo recibiendo el objeto en null

Comment: Intenta enviarlo con un formulario html, y serializas los datos.
`$('#formulario').serialize();`

Comment: Pero como puedo recibir el formulario completo en el controlador?

Comment: Utilizando el seralize() de Jquery. 

En html debes tener algo como esto:

`<form id="formulario" class="">
 <input type="text" name="primerdato" id="primerdato" >
 <input type="text" name="segundodato" id="segundodato" >
 <button type="submit" id="boton_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>`

Y en javascript:

`$('#formulario').serialize();`// primerdato=valor&segundodato=valor2

Luego en tu controlador lo recibes de esta forma:

`primerdato = $request->request->get("primerdato");`
`segundodato = $request->request->get("segundodato");`